# Automatic indentation text having brackets

Tags: indentation, brackets, formatter

I want to format the following automatically:

```
main[
  key1=value1
  key2=value2
  structure1=type1[
  key3=value3
  key4=value4
]
  structure4=type2[
  key5=value5
  key6=value6
]
  list=[elementType[
  key7=value7
  key8=value8
], elementType[
  key9=value9
  key10=value10
]]
]
```

My expectation is something like this:

```
main[
    key1=value1
    key2=value2
    structure1=type1[
        key3=value3
        key4=value4
    ]
    structure4=type2[
        key5=value5
        key6=value6
    ]
    list=[
        elementType[
            key7=value7
            key8=value8
        ], 
        elementType[
            key9=value9
            key10=value10
        ]
    ]
]
```

The original source is really huge. I want to do this once, therefore I do not need a generic solution.

Does anyone know about such an automatic formatter? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Java program for this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Formatter {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java Formatter filename");
        } else {
            List<String> lines = readFile(args[0]);
            int indent = 0;
            for (String line: lines) {
                String lineExtended = "x" + line + "x";
                indent -= (lineExtended.split("\\]").length - 1);
                for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++) {
                    System.out.print("\t");
                }
                System.out.println(line.trim());
                indent += (lineExtended.split("\\[").length - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<String> readFile(String filename) throws Exception {
        List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            records.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        return records;
    }
}
```

But I'm really curious if there exists a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

[There](https://github.com/ahuth/brackets-indentator) is a good extension. Press *CTRL+ALT+I* combination to format any code.

[image]

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: It sounds good, but at me it just removes the leading spaces.

Comment: A few steps ahead:
1. It is necessary to save the file with json extension to make it work, using your example.
2. It does not work with [], only with {}.
3. After replacing the [] brackets with {} the result is still strange using my example. At least it does not only remove the leading spaces, but the result is not what I expect.